# How can I close all NERTree buffers

Tags: buffers, plugin-nerdtree

When inside a session, I often end up with multiple tabs containing multiple split buffers and multiple "instances" of NerdTree buffers.

Is there a command to close all NerdTree buffers in the session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `tabdo` command:

```
:tabdo NERDTreeClose
```

This will execute the `NERDTreeClose` on every tab.